# how to avoid empty fields in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Frustrated with the Active Record Reputation gem, which I found very buggy, I'm trying to make my own reputation system for a Rails app. It's very primitive. I created a Contribution resource with a user_id and a value field, with an association between User.rb and Contribution.rb. Every time a user contributes to the app in some way, they get some points. If they ask a question, these lines get included in the create action of the Questions controller.

```
 @contribution = current_user.contributions.build({:value => 3})
 @contribution.save
```

If a user edits some Tags on the site, I do the same thing to reward superusers for their administrative work

```
 @contribution = current_user.contributions.build({:value => 2})
 @contribution.save
```

It then becomes very easy to calculate a user's total reputation.

One problem with this is that, in an imaginary world where users care about this app and their reputation, it would be very easy to game the system. For example, a user could just keep updating the categories or tags, and every time they do so they get 2 more points. Therefore, I wanted to somehow record what type of action the user did.

Right now, all of the work users can earn points for is somehow associated with a Question.rb, however, they get points for updating Tags, updating Categories, upvoting other people's answers etc, therefore merely storing the question_id in the contributions model wouldn't be sufficient.

Based on what I told you, can you give me some idea how I might build out the Contributions resource in order to accomplish what I want?

For example, I thought of one way of doing it that would have left a lot of null fields in my database, so I assumed it wasn't a good way. I could add a `question_id` and several boolean fields such as 'answering_question' '`updating_category`' '`updating_tags`' and each time an action is performed, record with a 'true' whether, for example, 'updating_category' is being performed. However, as mentioned, if I start rewarding lots of different types of contributions, there's going to be a lot of columns in each row that aren't being used.

I'm not sure if that's a 'real problem' (i've read about it but not sure how necessary it is to avoid), or if there's a better way of recording what type of activity each user is engaging in to earn points.

some of the current associations

```
User has_many :answers
Question.rb has_many :categories
Question.rb has_many :tags
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for my rails application I am using thumps_up gem which is better than active_record_reputations_system ,Its more simple.

https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation